# Get official PHP function Doc directly in Vim

Tags: php, vim

I want to know if is there a Vim plugin which integrates the PHP documentation of an official class or its methods directly in Vim.
Just Like pydoc.vim for Python:  [Pydoc.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/pydoc.vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use something like this in .vimrc

```
" F7 opens documentation for php/perl function under cursor
function! BrowseDoc()
    if b:current_syntax == "php"
        ! open "http://ch2.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=<cword>"
    elseif b:current_syntax == "perl"
        ! open http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=<cword>
    elseif b:current_syntax == "cpp"
          let cname = tolower(cword);
        ! open file:///opt/qt-4.3.4/doc/html/<cname>
    else
        return
    endif
endfunction
map <F7> :call BrowseDoc()^M^M
```

`open` is an OS X command, you may need to adapt that on other platforms

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but it will open documentation outside of VIm.  Maybe I must learn vim scripting to write my own custom plugins.

Comment: This is actually a great solution, it opens the docs in the environment that the docs were written for. It is also easily extensible and flexible. Thank you!